# Am I referring to doubt about who I love, or doubt about who the song is for?

Tags: meaning, phrases, syntactic-analysis

> This song's for the one I loved, at least that's what I thought.

My intent is to raise doubt about whether I love "the one", but I think "at least that's what I thought" could refer to the whole first half "This song's for the one I loved", i.e. I thought the song was for the one I loved.

Which interpretation is correct? If the second, what would be a proper way of saying this without really shortening the sentence?

Comment: You say "the sentence". How could that possibly refer to *love*?

Comment: No drop that. "This song's for the one I loved, at least that's what I thought" is the sentence I'm talking about. Atm

Comment: The second part of the sentence: "at least that's what I thought" was supposed to refer to the word "love" in the first sentence.

Comment: Ah, so you mean "This song is for the one I thought I loved", not "I thought this song was for the one I loved".

Comment: Exactly! So should I change it to "at least I thought I did" or something like that to get my message through or is it understandable as it is?

Comment: It's ambiguous, but because of context, it's understandable as is;  "at least I thought I did" also works. Use whichever sounds better in the song.

Comment: Pure literary interpretation is off-topic. 

Comment: Alright thanks a million! I'm not a native english speaker so I'm sorry if I couldn't make my intent clear. Still learning!

Comment: The first interpretation that came to my mind is "referring to doubt about who I love" but I can easily see the second interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

> This song's for the one I loved, at least I thought I did.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too..

Answer (score 1):

Just let it be.

The rhythm is much better than  any alternative currently listed in the answers, and the ambiguity does not detract at all from the thought.

This is a song after all, so a form of poetry, and ambiguity and artistic license are quite appropriate in such an instance.

Comment: That is true. To me it's all about the rhythm so I'd rather not change it. Thanks a lot mate!